# How to convert DateTime to String In dart?

Tags: api, flutter, datetime, parsing, dart

when it comes to api, "createdAt": "2021-01-23 19:26:00", how do I convert it as "January 23", for example?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**intl**](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. Consider a code snippet like a below:

```
main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2021-06-19
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty straightforward way to read dates and write them in any format. Here is just one sample:

```
DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(DateTime.parse("2021-01-23 19:26:00"))
```

Here is the article about [working with dates](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-dates-in-dart-e81c70911811).

Here is the sample to localize the date with `Intl` package:

```
Intl.defaultLocale = 'es';
DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.now());
```

Comment: it works, but how can I translate it into my own language? are there docs about it?

Comment: Take a look on the article, it shows the way to choose format. Or what do you mean but you own language?

Comment: it mean  look  localizations i can't

Comment: you can do it with `Intl` package. I've added it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [moment](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_moment)

```dart
Moment.parse(createdAt).format(DATE_FORMAT); // replace DATE_FORMAT with the date format you need
```

Or you can do it yourself using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package:

```dart
final DateFormat format = DateFormat.yMd('fr');
var formattedDate = format.format(DateTime.parse("2021-01-23 19:26:00"));
```

Comment: it works, but how can I translate it into my own language? are there docs about it?

Comment: Do you mean to internationalise ?

Comment: I just want to translate the names of the months in English into my own language?

Comment: And what is your language? Both solutions I've provided support locale customisation

Comment: my language is Azerbaijani.

Answer (score 0):

Install the intl package by running below command in your terminal:

```
dart pub add intl
```

Import the package in your class:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


main(){
    final DateTime date = DateTime.now();
    final String formatted = DateFormat.yMd().format(date);
    print(formatted); // something like 06/21/2021
}
```